# can (should) I use Flink like an in-memory database?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I've used batch Beam but am new to the streaming interface. I'm wondering about the appropriateness of using Apache Flink / Beam kind of like an in-memory database -- I'd like to constantly recompute and materialize one specific view of my data based on edge triggered updates.

More details: I have a few tables in a (normal) database, ranging from thousands to millions of rows, and each one has a many-to-many (M2M) relationship with other ones. Picture to explain:

```
  Hosts  <-M2M #1->  Table 1  <-M2M #2->  Table 2  <-M2M #3->  Table 3
```

`Table 1` is a set of objects that the hosts need to know about, and each host needs to know about all downstream rows referenced directly or indirectly by the objects in `Table 1` that it's related to. When changes happen anywhere other than the first many-to-many relationship `M2M #1`, it's not obvious which hosts need to be updated without traversing "left" to find the hosts and then traversing "right" to get all the necessary configuration. The objects and relationships at most levels change frequently, and I need sub-second latency to go from "a record or relationship changed" to recalculating any flattened config files with changes in them so that I can push updates to the hosts very quickly.

Is this an appropriate use case for streaming Flink / Beam? I have worked with Beam in a different system but only in batch mode, and I think that it would be a great tool to use here if I could edge-trigger it. The part I'm getting stuck on is, in batch mode, the `PCollections` are all "complete" in the sense that I can always join all records in one table with all records in another table. But with streaming, once I process a record once, it gets removed from its `PCollection` and can't be joined against future updates that arrive later on and relate to it, right? IIUC, it's only available within a window, but I effectively want an infinitely long window where only outdated versions of items in a `PCollection` (e.g. versions of them which have been overwritten by a new version that came in over the stream) would be freed up.

(Also, to bootstrap this system, I would need to scan the whole database to prefill all the state before I could start reading from a stream of edge-triggered updates. Is that a common pattern?)

Comment: After reading more about it, I’m pretty sure my understanding is right and this model just isn’t really a good fit. I think my use case probably maps more obviously to a graph database.

Comment: (Or perhaps an RDBMS, depending on performance / ease of use.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about Beam to answer that part of the question, but you can certainly use Flink in the way you've described. The simplest way to accomplish this with Flink is with a streaming join, using the SQL/Table API. The runtime will materialize both tables into managed Flink state, and produce new and/or updated results as new and updated records are processed from the input tables. This is a commonly used pattern.

As for initially bootstrapping the state, before continuing to ingest the updates, I suggest using a CDC-based approach. You might start by looking at https://github.com/ververica/flink-cdc-connectors.